# symfony form : Date is not valid

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I use symfony with fosrestBundle.

I try to update an entity.

I have a mysql database with a field "myDate" witch is a date (not a datetime)

When i get my entity, i have this in the json response :

```
myDate:"2010-12-20T00:00:00+01:00"
```

When i update my entity, i send the same data.

On the computer of my friend, it works, but on mine, i have this error :

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": {
    "children": {
      ...,
      "myDate": {
        "errors": [
          "Cette valeur n'est pas valide."
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the FormType builder, i have this :

```
->add('myDate', 'date', [
    'widget' => 'single_text'
])
```

If i deplace 'date' with DateTimeType::class, i know it will works but what i want to know is why does this woks for my friend and not for me ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe the symfony cache ?

Comment: Cache was cleared

Answer (score 1):

The controller expects a date object from the form; if you don't use a transformer (more about Symfony Transformers [here][1]) to convert your form data from string to Date object, it throws the error.

You have two obtions:

1) Use the Transformer to change your data type before it is processed by the Controller

or:

2) Change in your FormBuilder "DateType" to 'TextType' & remove all the Date optons (widget').

Good luck